# Small basic turtle

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-c++, basic

I am attempting to draw a parallelogram using the turtle in Small Basic. The sides should be 120px and 200px. The inside angle for the parallelogram should be 60°. I am able to get the shape but the angle part is confusing me, it says the inside angle should be 60 how would I code this? Here is what I got so far which draws a simple rectangle:

```
Turtle.Angle = 60
Turtle.Move(120)
Turtle.TurnRight()
Turtle.Move(200)
Turtle.TurnRight()
Turtle.Move(120)
Turtle.TurnRight()
Turtle.Move(200)
Turtle.TurnRight()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of two things here instead:

```
Turn(60)
```

...would allow you to turn your Turtle through a fixed angle, rather than the fixed 90-degree turns of TurnLeft() or TurnRight().  Alternatively instead, you could use the same command you have in the first line:

```
Turtle.Angle = 60
```

...and set the angle explicitly, rather than using the Turn function to control it.  Either will allow you to change your Turtle's direction with more precision.

Comment: so this is how its suppose to look like https://imgur.com/Um0kgok , but mine looks like this https://imgur.com/9PFcD6G. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?